Can't upload media or elementor pro to wordpress site
I imported a site from one wordpress website to another and I can't upload elementor pro and my images just appear as a blank thumbnail on the site. How do I update file permissions What's the problem?
I increased the server size but I'm not sure what else to do. I need elementor pro and I have to have images
